According to the 4 Madhabs, Do Verses Like 2:194 Permit Seeking Retribution Against Woman and Children Who Do Not Bear Arms?

“Ibn Uthaymeen said: and the second benefit is; the prohibition of killing women and children during war.
And if it is said, if they did this to us, that they killed our children and women, can we kill them? What is apparent, is that it is allowed for us to kill their women and children, even if that were to cause us to miss taking them as wealth, due to what this contains from breaking the hearts of the enemies and weakening them, and due to the generality of Allah’s saying, “And whoever transgresses against you, then transgress against them the like of what they have transgressed against you, — Q2:194.”
The questioner continues: then we are allowed to kill their women and children. But O sheikh, they, the men are the ones who killed the women, and the women are innocent, so how can they be punished due to the crimes of men?
Ibn Uthaymeen replied: This is because of the greater benefit, the greater benefit to those who are fighting. Because if we do not do to them what they do to us, this would be humiliation in front of them.
Ibn Uthaymeen continued: Justice with their woman is incomprehensible, they killed our women, we kill their women. This is justice. It is not justice that we say, if they kill our women we will not kill their women. Also, we note that this influences them greatly.”
— Bulugh Al-Maram, Explanation by Ibn Uthaymeen, Tape 3, Side B.

The focus of this ticket is as follows:

What is the reliability of this attribution to Ibn Uthaymeen?
If it's reliable, is he really saying that, based off of Q2:194, if
the enemy kills our non-fighters; more specifically, woman and children who do not take part in battle, we may do the same to them as a
form of retaliation?
Most importantly, how well reflected is this position within the
mainstream/ classical understanding Islamic jurisprudence; the
opinions of the fuquha within the 4 madhabs?


Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته, I will do that, thank you! Also, if you could possibly provide an answer to my question, that would be much appreciated!

I did some superficial research I'd say the statements above are seemingly collected from different parts of the same tape the part till the quotation of the verse appears of example https://alathar.net/home/esound/index.php?op=codevi&coid=32866

Wow, so this seems to be a reliable attribution to Ibn Uthaymeen, that's quite disappointing to hear honestly. Could you care to answer questions 2 and 3 as well? I'd honestly prefer a complete answer rather than a comment, if possible that is.

As far as the classical viewpoint is concerned, the killing women and children can be one of two types: collateral or targeted.
Collateral killing:
This includes situations such as:

Use of catapults to bombard a city
Setting fire to a settlement
Drowning a settlement under water by diverting a river or breaking a dam
Besieging or blockading the settlement preventing inflow of essential supplies
Attacking at night when it is not possible to distinguish between male\female and adult\child due to darkness and proximity of the people
Shooting at the enemy when they have women and children among them or use them as human shields or hostages

Use of such weapons and strategies is permissible. The Muslims will aim for the adult males but it is forgiven if any women or children end up dying as a result.

المحرم إنما هو قصد قتلهن فأما إذا قصدنا قصد الرجال بالإغارة أو نرمي منجنيق أو فتح شق أو إلقاء نار فتلف بذلك نساء أو صبيان لم نأثم بذلك لحديث الصعب بن جثامة أنه سأل النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عن أهل الدار من المشركين يبيتون فيصاب الذرية فقال "هم منهم" متفق عليه ولأن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم رمى أهل الطائف بالمنجنيق مع أنه قد يصيب المرأة والصبي
It is only forbidden to intentionally aim to kill the women and children. However if we aim for the men in a night raid, or when shooting a catapult, or when demolishing a dam, or when throwing fire and that causes casualties of women and children then we do not earn sin because of that because of the hadith of Sa’b bin Jaththamah that he asked the Prophet ﷺ about the killing women and children during night raids on the polytheists and he replied "They are of them" which is agreed upon (recorded by Bukhari and Muslim) and because the Prophet ﷺ shot at the people of Ta'if with a catapult and that could cause casualties of women and children
— Saarim al-Maslool


ويجوز حصار الكفار في البلاد والحصون والقلاع، وإرسال الماء عليهم، ورميهم بنار ومنجنيق وما في معنى ذلك من هدم بيوتهم، وقطع الماء عنهم، وإلقاء حيات أو عقارب عليهم ولو كان فيهم نساء وصبيان
And it is permissible to besiege the disbelievers in settlements, fortresses and castles. And to let lose flood water on them, and to shoot fire and catapults at them, and whatever else comes under the meaning of that such as demolishing their homes, and cutting off their water, and throwing snakes and scorpions on them even if there are women and children among them
— Mughni al-Muhtaaj


ولا بأس بإحراق حصونهم بالنار، وإغراقها بالماء، وتخريبها وهدمها عليهم، ونصب المنجنيق عليها؛ لقوله - تبارك وتعالى:  يخربون بيوتهم بأيديهم وأيدي المؤمنين
There is no harm in burning their fortresses with fire, flooding them with water, destroying and demolishing them upon them, and setting up catapults against them; due to the saying of Allah: "they destroyed their houses with their own hands and the hands of the believers"
— Badaa'i' as-Sanaa'i'


واتفق عوام الفقهاء على جواز رمي الحصون بالمجانيق، سواء كان فيها نساء وذرية، أو لم يكن
Most of the jurists agree on the permissibility of shooting at fortresses with catapults, regardless of whether they contain women and children or not
— Bidaayat al-Mujtahid

Targeted killing:
This means killing them intentionally when it is feasible to avoid killing them. An example of this is where they are in a separate location from the enemy, or where they have already been overpowered and captured etc.
In this case if they personally participate in fighting then they can be killed. This can be during combat or even after capture. Participation can be directly by bearing arms or indirectly such as by giving advice or arousing others to fight etc.
In the absence of personal participation, many classical scholars have noted that it is not permitted to kill them intentionally. For example:

لا خلاف بينهم في أنه لا يجوز قتل صبيانهم ولا قتل نسائهم ما لم تقاتل المرأة والصبي
There is no disagreement among them that it is not permissible to kill their children or their women, as long as the woman and the child do not participate in fighting
— Bidaayat al-Mujtahid


أجمع العلماء على ... وتحريم قتل النساء والصبيان إذا لم يقاتلوا
The scholars have a consensus that ... it is forbidden to kill women and children if they do not participate in fighting
— Sharah Nawawi


لا تقتل نساؤهم إلا أن يقاتلن بقول أو عمل باتفاق العلماء
Their women should not be killed unless they fight with words or actions, according to the agreement of scholars
— Majmoo‘ al-Fataawa

The texts above suggest that targeting women and children specifically as retaliation (for the actions of others) is not permissible, as this is not listed as an exception.
Currently I am not aware of any classical scholars who explicitly mentioned this sort of retaliation as an exception (if someone is aware of any then please comment or edit this post with references). Some contemporary fatwas I came across have negated it as being an exception, see https://islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/46548/
While some other sources accept it as an exception by using analogy with the fact that some other forbidden actions (like fighting in the sacred months or mutilation of dead bodies) become permissible if done in retaliation.

I have a couple follow up questions if you don't mind, regarding the 1st part of your answer, would you say that the majority of the classical fuquha would believe it is permissible to, lets say, spread bombs across a whole city that includes like, 90% non-fighters, so woman, children, elderly, ect, anyone who is not capable of fighting, as long as there is a possibility of killing a couple fighters? So essentially if a place has like 1000 non-fighters, and there are maybe 100 or so fighters, would it be permissible, according to them, to bomb that place, or set fire to it and so on?

Likewise, regarding the 2nd part, you mentioned that as long as they are just arousing others with words, it is permissible to kill them? Does this include children as well; children who simply support the enemy because their parents tell them to do so? Likewise, what exactly is meant here by "arousing others with words"? Does that mean like simply giving the enemy a boost of morale, or would it be more accurate to define it as giving them advice and counsel? I've never heard that simply logistical support from woman and children allows the Muslims to now fight them...

outside of maybe the Shafii madhab. I'd appreciate if you could provide more evidences that simply logistical support entails combatancy according to the jamhurayra.
